# Marklogic 6: Dls version restoring issue

Tags: marklogic

Hi I have used this below mention dls function . But i got some error in result window.Please suggest me anything missing my side?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

  import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
      at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

  dls:document-update(
           "/foo/bar/baz.xml",
```

**ERROR**

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-DUPATTR: (err:XQDY0025) $child -- Two attributes with the same name

Stack Trace
In /MarkLogic/dls.xqy on line 1386
In add-xml-base(fn:doc("/foo/bar/baz_xml_versions/1-baz.xml")/ca, "/foo/bar/baz.xml")

$node := fn:doc("/foo/bar/baz_xml_versions/1-baz.xml")/ca
$uri := "/foo/bar/baz.xml"
$child := fn:doc("/foo/bar/baz_xml_versions/1-baz.xml")/ca/@xml:base
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error based on xml-base name which is available in Marklogic/dls.xqy file. In the Function add-xml-base in dls.xqy file, check any condition available before returning the output value.The condition should check the xml base name and the names didn't match then return the output value. The below example will solve your issue.

```
declare private function add-xml-base(
  $node as node(),
  $uri as xs:string)
{
  element { fn:node-name($node) } { 
    ( 
      attribute xml:base { $uri },
      for $child in ($node/@*, $node/node())
        where (fn:name($child) ne "xml:base") 
        return $child
    )
  }
};
```